# Segregate routes and controller in sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Currently `Sinatra` controller looks like this,

```
class UserController < Sinatra::Base
 get '/' do
  # code goes here
 end
end
```

How can I make it like `Rails`

```
# routes.rb
 get '/user' => 'user_controller#index'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do a method that create routes.

See the example that I did:

```rb
require 'sinatra'

class UserController
  def index
    'UserController -> index!'
  end

  def posts
    'UserController -> posts!'
  end
end

def route_get(url, call)
  controller_class, method = call.split('#')
  controller_class = Object.const_get(controller_class)

  Sinatra::Base.get url do
    controller_class.new.send(method)
  end
end

route_get '/', 'UserController#index'
route_get '/users', 'UserController#index'
route_get '/users/posts', 'UserController#posts'
```

If you like, you can do for other methods HTTP. Or you can do pass others arguments.

Comment: In this example don't need, because I call `Sinatra::Base` in `route_get` function.

Comment: `controller_class.new` is throwing error, I have to use new! instead.

Comment: it would be nice if this code can pass `params` `request` from route to controller